# Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined" in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I used same approach as [here](https://codepen.io/mburridge/pen/WgXrvG) to make something similar but when ever I click on buttons sometimes it happens right away sometimes after 20 clicks....

Here is my code: (Inside .vue file)

```
<template>
<div class="right-bar" :class="{'hide':!open}">
    <div class="header-bar">
        <button @click="changeTab(1)" class="hbm" :class="[ activetab === 1 ? 'active' : '' ]">
            <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
        </button>
        <button @click="changeTab(2)" class="hbm" :class="[ activetab === 2 ? 'active' : '' ]">
            <i class="fas fa-comments"></i>
        </button>
        <button @click="changeTab(3)" class="hbm" :class="[ activetab === 3 ? 'active' : '' ]">
            <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
        </button>
        <button @click="changeTab(4)" class="hbm" :class="[ activetab === 4 ? 'active' : '' ]">
            <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
        </button>
        <i class="fas rs-btn" :class="[open?'fa-chevron-down':'fa-chevron-up']" @click.prevent="open=!open"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="content-form">
        <div class="form" v-if="activetab === 1">
            <slot name="overview"></slot>
        </div>
        <div class="form" v-if="activetab === 2">
            <slot name="messages"></slot>
        </div>
        <div class="form" v-if="activetab === 3">
            <slot name="notifications"></slot>
        </div>
        <div class="form" v-if="activetab === 4">
            <slot name="settings"></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                open: true,
                activetab: 1
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changeTab(i) {
                this.activetab = i;
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Here is a quick video of it: (because as I said some times it happens in few some times in lot clicks)

https://streamable.com/zpk4m

Both versions are 2.5.17 but I use one with laravel fresh installation..
Also I have installed vuex and lodash... if it means something

Comment: when do you get the error cited in the question title?

Comment: I think the problem isn't in the tabs, but in the tabs content.
I presume that you are using `v-for` inside some tabs, because of this you are setting the `key` atribute on the iterated nodes to provide a unique key to Vue manage it's own cache with that nodes. Check the `key` your are setting in the tabs, change it's value for each tab and check if it persists, example: `:key="'tab-1-' + item.id"`

Comment: @Giovane that case doesn't generate that error

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim I added small video when it happens, when I click buttons few or more times between eachother

Comment: @Giovane I am not using `v-for`, but I am using laravel `foreach()`, where should item.id come from?

Comment: please provide your data object

Comment: yes i see but the 1st warn in the video could be generated if you're using `data:{..}` instead of `data(){...}`

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim that was always there and i couldnt find answer for it, and i causes no problems. But Giovane was right my laravel foreach seems to make a problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181812/discussion-between-boussadjra-brahim-and-learner).

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim I found out the problem, it was with slots... I duplicated same element within slot: Tab>slot=overview and I called that slot with same tab element that why it was crashing, elements were duplicated :O I am so blind and stupid :D

Comment: it's good try to edit your question to specify the problem and the solution

Comment: sure I will ... :D

Answer (score 3):

Answer in my case was duplication of elements:

My tab element is:

```
<div class="form" v-if="activetab === 2">
     <slot name="messages"></slot>
</div>
```

and for slot I used:

```
<div class="form" slot="messages">

</div>
```

I duplicated same element and caused which caused crashing :D